# Using Spyder IDE: SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop

Tags: python, spyder

I downloaded Sypder and I keep getting the error below when I run the script in the interpreter.

```
>>> continue
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop
```

This happens even on a simple hello world script:

```
print('hello world!')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [syntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14312869/syntaxerror-continue-not-properly-in-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button I was clicking was the 'continue' button. It looks like a play button like in MATLAB. The actual run button is the green circle, just in case anybody runs into this silly little mistake as well. Thanks for the response Prahaland.

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) Yes, that's the right answer. We will fix this inconsistency in our next release. Thanks for your patience :-)

Comment: Please take a look at our 2.2.2 version. It has a revamped icon set so people doesn't encounter this problem again

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I'm getting this same problem running Spyder 2.2.5.

Comment: @Addem then you're pressing the wrong button. The Run button is the button with a big Play arrow (▶) in green.

Comment: @Carlos Cordoba, sorry, just realized the OP was getting the error all the time. I get the error when i try to use break points and press the bottom that looks like two play buttons on top of each other.

Comment: @Addem I don't know what could be happening. Please open a new issue in our [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/list) and upload there a simple example file that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please provide your script? Are you encountering this problem when running python in a n interactive mode on the python interpreter within Spyder?

There are some links on Google groups that discuss this problem:

[Google Groups Spyder problems](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/spyderlib/KvtAVn2Iqv8/Mm_4xqNqp7wJ).

Please refer to the responses at the end of the page that points to some solution.