# Automate the Boring Stuff Chapter 11 Step 3

Tags: python, syntax-error, continue

I've managed to iron out the bugs previous to this one showing up and I've copied the code exactly as is stated in the chapter but I am getting this error being thrown up and I can't seem to fix it:

> File "xkcd.py", line 34
>   continue
>    ^
>   SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop.

Here is my code:

```
comicElem = soup.select('#comic img')  
if comicElem == []:
    print('could not find comic image.')
else:
    try:
        comicUrl = 'http:' + comicElem[0].get('src')
        # Download the image.
        print('Downloading image %s...' % (comicUrl))
        res = requests.get(comicUrl)
        res.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.MissingSchema:
        # skip this comic
        prevLink = soup.select('a[rel="prev"]')[0]
        url = 'http://xkcd.com' + prevLink.get('href')
        continue
```

I understand the obvious, because of the error being perfectly clear but as a newbie copying code straight from the site and not coming across this sort of thing previously, I am struggling to understand where the issue really is.

Comment: There is no loop. `continue` advances to the next iteration.

Comment: What you you expect the `continue` to do where you've placed it?

Comment: I haven't placed it there as something I have personally written. This has come from the website "automate the boring stuff with python" and this is copied exactly as it is written on the site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [syntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14312869/syntaxerror-continue-not-properly-in-loop)

Answer (score 0):

continue should be used inside of a loop (for, while). There is no loop in your code.