# How do I rectify the error "SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop" in python?

Tags: python, syntax-error

How do I rectify the error "SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop
" in python?

```
matches = re.search("Temp =\s+([0-9.]+)", output)
 if ( not matches):
 time.sleep(0)
 continue
```

Comment: Your indentation is broken, whether or not the posted code occurs in a loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [syntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14312869/syntaxerror-continue-not-properly-in-loop)

Answer (score 1):

`continue` is allowed only in `for` or `while` loops. Looks like it's redundant here. In case this is part of a loop, please post that part of your code as well.